# Word Web - A Hard One

Tags: word, connect-wall

> Disclaimer: "Hard" here is not a difficulty indicator. Please do not edit the title.

This is a Word Web. Divide the 16 words into four groups of four such that they can collocate with one same word. Then find the answer that collocates with the four derived word. (-ed) means the derived word has an -ed suffix in those cases. Have fun!

```
(-ed) Coffee     Copper       Dietary        Health
   Hormone        Ion          Iron          Mental
   Mining     Nutritional     Sports        Staffing
    Test       Treatment      Vitamin     (-ed) Water
```

Hint 1

> `Dietary` is not in the same group as `Treatment`

Hint 2

> `Test` is not in the same group as `Iron`

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two groups have already been found by others:

> DEFICIENCY : Hormone, Staffing, Mental, Nutritional
>  SUPPLEMENT: Dietary, Health, Sports, Vitamin

I guessed

> CARBONATE: copper, iron, ion, _ed water

which is apparently the right connecting word but only 2/4 of the right items. JS1 has proposed a different division of the remaining words into two fours, which if I understand OP's comments correctly is right. So, apparently, we have

> CARBONATE: _ed water, _ed coffee, test, ion

leaving

> copper, iron, mining, treatment

for which I don't currently have a really convincing guess at the connecting word, but here are two suggestions

> ORE or OXIDE

neither of which I'm in love with; as for the final answer, since my first conjecture for it was wrong I shall instead propose

> CALCIUM (which, it occurs to me, makes some sense of the title, since calcium carbonate is what makes "hard" water hard).

Credit where due: OP gave some feedback on the first and third versions of this answer; JonMark Perry pointed out that the second version was inconsistent with one of OP's hints; JS1 found what I think OP has said is the correct division of the last 8 words.

Comment: third group word 1/1, members 2/4, and the 4th grp isn't a metal

Comment: Clarification: I wasn't saying the fourth group is a metal, I was saying I expect the _final answer_ to be one. (My guess at the word for the fourth group was not in any sense a metal.) Anyway, thanks for the feedback; will update accordingly.

Comment: the second hint says iron and test aren't in the same group.

Comment: Ooh, so it does. I'll try again. (The difficulty here is that there seem to be lots of ways to divide these words into four groups of four that connect about equally well. Perhaps the _right_ answer is to figure out the meta and backsolve.)

Comment: c word is right, but not salt and the answer. keep it up!

Comment: Would you like to indicate whether I now have the last two groups right? (Their contents, I mean; I know I have one connecting word right and one wrong.)

Comment: sorry, i wasnt pinged until i came across this. the shorter o word is the answer, and the answer is correct! well done!

Answer (score 5):

Group 1

> DEFICIENCY : Hormone, Staffing, Mental, Nutritional
>  SUPPLEMENT: Dietary, Health, Sports, Vitamin
>  CARBONATE: Coffee, Ion, Test, Water
>  ?????????: Copper, Iron, Mining, Treatment

Comment: correct grouping word, but not these four items! keep it up!

Comment: is it coffee? :) or staffing?

Comment: wrong second grp, nailed first. well done!

Comment: hmmm... im gonna give a hint... what sort of hint do you want?

Comment: I've tried Fibre, Supplement, Centre, Chill(ed), Blood, World and Complex, but nothing. And knowing that the answer is a chemical isn't helping either! An anti-pair (A is NOT related to B) maybe?

Comment: in fact, one of the words in the list is the right grouping word...

Comment: added hint as requested!

Comment: do you needa hint?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton; okay, another anti-clue would be great!

Comment: added as requested!

Comment: sorry not a word nor c word

Answer (score 3):

What I have so far:

> **DEFICIENCY**: Hormone, Mental, Nutritional, Staffing (@JonMark Perry)
>  **SUPPLEMENT**: Dietary, Health, Sports, Vitamin (confirmed)
>  **CARBONATE**: (-ed) Coffee, Ion, Test, (-ed) Water (@Gareth McCaughan, to be confirmed)
>  **???**: Copper, Iron, Mining, Treatment

Old guesses with feedback:

> **DRIVE**: Health, Ion, Sports, Test (all wrong)
>  **ICE**: Coffee, Mining, Treatment, Water (all wrong)
>  **MINERAL**: Copper, Ion, Iron, Mining (wrong group name, 3/4 words)
>  **METAL**: Copper, Iron, Mining, Treatment (wrong group name, 4/4 words)
>  **SOURCE**: Coffee, Ion, Test, Water (wrong group name, 4/4 words)
>  **SURFACE**: Copper, Iron, Mining, Treatment (wrong group name)
>  **WASTE**: Copper, Iron, Mining, Treatment (wrong group name)

Comment: group 2 all correct, well done!

Comment: new guess name 0/1, words 3/4

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I have new guesses for groups 3 and 4.

Comment: two groups word 0/2, members 8/8

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I added a guess based on Gareth's group plus two of my own for the 4th group.  I figured I would submit multiple guesses to waste less of your time.

Comment: sorry not surface nor waste