# Connect Wall: Visual Edition

Tags: connect-wall

It feels like a while since the last Connect Wall, so here is one. As usual, there are 16 words which can be grouped into sets of four with each group associated with a word. The resulting four words also have a connection, but in this case, the final connection is a **picture**, not a word or phrase. (Well, actually it could be represented by a phrase, but the answer is a picture.) The words are:

BULLET, BUTTER, DRY, FOOL, GLASS, HAZEL, HERO, HOUSE, JACOB, MAY, PARTY, PRINCE, SILHOUETTE, TRIBE, VILLA, WATCH

**HINT**

> GLASS and WATCH are in the same group.

**HINT**

> FOOL and TRIBE are in the same group.

**HINT**

> PRINCE and HAZEL are in different groups.

**HINT**

> HAZEL is meant to be used as a proper name, and is in the same group as PARTY.

**HINT**

> The group including PRINCE is based on song titles. The group including HAZEL is based on a recent event in my neck of the woods (southeastern US).

Comment: For those of us who aren't familiar with "connect wall", Does *"associated with a word"* mean, *"can be preceded or followed by a word"*?  Or can "associated" have a wider meaning?

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Take a look at other puzzles with the [tag:connect-wall] tag - there are lots of examples on this site now :) (Usually on PSE most questions use precede/follow, but the [original intention of this puzzle type](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/60644) has a much wider application of connection...)

Comment: Still feel like I've only got two of the groups for this (the ones involving BULLET and BUTTER) - how on earth do you get a connection with SILHOUETTE?! Impressive word to fit into a puzzle like this...

Comment: @Stiv I gotta say I was ecstatic to find I could use SILHOUETTE...you will appreciate it when you get it, I think. Ready for a hint?

Comment: That latest clue confirms something I've wondered since the very start about PRINCE. But that HAZEL group's connection is driving me nuts! Will see if it clicks tonight - without it, the main connection is still obscure...

Comment: @Stiv True...that last connection is the keystone. Don't worry about struggling...it is much more an American phenomenon.

Comment: @Stiv I have the HAZEL category, I think — but not the others — think a rot13(ymetr angheny curabzraba) in the location Jeremy mentioned....

Comment: Thanks @El-Guest - that helped. Definitely wasn't on my radar! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 4 groups in this tricky connecting wall are:

> **GROUP 1: ___FLY**
>  BUTTERfly, HOUSEfly, MAYfly, [DRY fly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dry%20fly).
>
>  **GROUP 2: ___IN**
>  BULLETin, VILLAin, HEROin, [JACOBin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobin).
>
>  **GROUP 3: TWO ___S (songs)**
>  [Two PRINCEs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsdy_rct6uo), [Two TRIBEs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXWVpcypf0w), [Two SILHOUETTES](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xoqIeUo5S8), [Two FOOLs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTSI42a6sHY).
>
>  **GROUP 4: HURRICANE ___**
>  [Hurricane HAZEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Hazel), [Hurricane WATCH](https://www.yourdictionary.com/hurricane-watch), [Hurricane PARTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_party), [Hurricane GLASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_glass).

After some consideration of exactly how to use the information (spending far too long trying to interpret it as a cryptic clue, given the OP's other puzzles!), I finally realised that to find the picture connection, we simply need to arrange these four connecting words into a literal phrase:

> **FLY TWO IN HURRICANE**

This means that our picture answer is:

> [image]
>  *<sup>Source: Wikipedia</sup>*
>
>  This is the US maritime flag for a [storm warning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_warning). The use of *two* such flags *flying* together at the same time indicates a ***hurricane* warning**...

Comment: Excellent! Those are the groups. But the use of rot13(gjb) vs. rot13(gb) was deliberate. Try juggling the word order around a little bit...another tip: I could give this away with a standard tag that I've used before.

Comment: @JeremyDover I'm guessing this is a particular tag you've used a lot(!) - I can half-justify rot13(ZBFDHVGB be OYBJ-SYL) but not quite fully satisfactorily yet... Is this the right kind of lines?

Comment: Think of the last of your puzzles that I solved...

Comment: That's it Stiv! Great work...thank you for sticking with it! I always love all the links in your answers, BTW :-)