# Another Visual Connect Wall

Tags: pattern, connect-wall

Inspired by [this recent Connect Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100752/connect-wall-visual-edition)

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups of 4 connected words.
The resulting four words also have a connection, but in this case, the final connection is a **picture**, not a word or phrase.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FLEA | FOX | FROG | TARANTULA |
| STAND | SAID | BURNS | BLACK |
| GRASS | SHADE | FURLONG | CLOD |
| HUDSON | JAR | WAR | FALL |

**Can you identify the four groups and the associated group-words?**
**What is the picture that links the group-words together?**

Comment: Nice puzzle! Really like the connection at the end!

Comment: Thanks @JeremyDover and thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> [image]
>   <sup>*Nighthawks by Edward Hopper; Source: Wikipedia*</sup>

The four groups are:

> **NIGHT**:
>  [image]
>   <sup>*A NIGHTjar; Source: Britannica.com*</sup> 
> (NIGHT)SHADE, a [family of plants including many fruits and vegetables](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321745)
>  (NIGHT)FALL, when it gets dark
> (NIGHT)JAR, a beautiful bird
> (NIGHT)STAND, the piece of furniture.

> **HAWK**:
>  [image].
>  <sup>*Hudson HAWK; Source: filmstories.co.uk*</sup> 
>  TARANTULA (HAWK), a [frightening wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarantula_hawk)
>  WAR (HAWK), [politician in favor of war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hawk)
>  BLACK (HAWK), a [famous Sauk Native American leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hawk_(Sauk_leader)) (or boring helicopter)
>  HUDSON (HAWK), a [Bruce Willis action-comedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_Hawk)

> **EDWARD**: All answers are famous EDWARDs!
>  [image]
>  <sup>*EDWARD Said; Source: en.qantara.de*</sup> 
>  (EDWARD) FURLONG, an [actor that I think I recognize?](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000411/)
>  (EDWARD) SAID, [famed professor and author of Orientalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Said)
>  (EDWARD) FOX, another [slightly recognizable actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Fox_(actor)), or any of [these guys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Fox_(actor))
>  (EDWARD) BURNS, I definitely [recognize this actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Burns), but probably couldn't normally name him

> **HOPPER**: thought all were insects, but clodHOPPER is a shoe
>  [image]
>  <sup>*frogHOPPER; Source: wlgf.org*</sup> 
>  FLEA(HOPPER), insect
>  GRASS(HOPPER), insect
>  CLOD(HOPPER), a shoe or fool
>  FROG(HOPPER), insect

Comment: Perfect. I like the style of your answer too.