# A Connecting Wall off the beaten track!

Tags: knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

This is an extended hybrid [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle which fuses components of the most common PSE strain (where group connections also have one final connection, which is the puzzle's answer) with a variety of [connecting methods](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/60644) used in the original BBC TV series, *[Only Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect)*. This means that not all groups are of the commonly used 'linking word which can precede/follow the given word' mould - bear that in mind!

Also, for this Connecting Wall, you will need to partition a larger number of clues (**24** of them) into **6 sets of 4**. Once all 6 sets are found, you need to provide a specific 4-letter word that links the 6 connections - this is the final answer for the puzzle.

Good luck!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASTERISK | BEFORE | BELOW | COMMODORE |
| CZECHOSLOVAKIA | F | GUFFAW | HARRISON |
| ISAIAH | LOIRE | METAPHOR | MILE |
| MM | MYERS-BRIGGS | POOL | POUND |
| QUINCE | ROBINSON | SEMAPHORE | SNES |
| SUPER | V | WHISKEY | XV |

> **TASK:
>
> (1) Partition this Connecting Wall into 6 sets of 4 clues (various connecting methods);
>
> (2) Find the final 4-letter connection between the 6 connections.**

(Note that once you pinpoint a couple of groups correctly, you may gain an idea as to where this is going and be able to find the others much more quickly!)

Comment: Would the puzzle work without all caps? Not sure if that's a clue or to throw us off or irrelevant

Comment: @Jay All-caps is purely for consistent aesthetics :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Connections

> **Group 1**
>  Words that contain the sound **FOUR** - Before, Guffaw, Metaphor, Semaphore
>  **Group 2**
>  Words that form movie titles when combined with the number **EIGHT** - [Eight Below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Below), [8 Mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_Mile_(film)), [8MM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8mm_(film)), [Super 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_8_(2011_film))
>  **Group 3**
>  Words that mean **FIFTEEN** - F (hexadecimal), Quince (Spanish), XV (Roman numerals), Commodore (Cockney rhyming slang) (credit to BeastlyGerbil for spotting this in the comments)
>  **Group 4**
>  Things that are composed of **SIXTEEN** parts - Myers-Briggs (16 categories), SNES (16-bit), Pound (16 ounces), Pool (16 balls) 
>  **Group 5**
>  Words which are **TWENTY-THREE** in an ordering - Harrison (23rd U.S. President), Isaiah (23rd book of the Bible), V (23rd chemical symbol of the periodic table), Whiskey (23rd letter of the NATO phonetic alphabet), 
>  **Group 6**
>  Words associated with the number **FORTY-TWO** - Asterisk (decimal code), Czechoslovakia (calling code),  Loire (France department number), [Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Robinson) (famous for wearing number 42)

So the categories are

> 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42

And we recognise these as being

> The six numbers that reappear consistently in the TV show [*Lost*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(TV_series))

So the four-letter word must be

> Lost

Title

> "Off the beaten track" means in an isolated place. In the TV show *Lost*, the characters are trapped on a mysterious remote island when their plane crashes.

Comment: YES hexomino! To fix the one inconsistency, GUFFAW is in the wrong group. Spot where it should be instead and you can tighten up *that* group's definition even tighter... Well done :) (PS Loose connection with the title...?)

Comment: rot13: Thssnj naq pbzzbqber fubhyq or fjvgpurq, thssnj eulzrf jvgu sbhe naq pbzzbqber vf fynat sbe 15 cbhaqf :) (think this is right @Stiv?)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Exactly right :) Although if you look, that group's connection is even tighter than just a rot13(eulzr)...

Comment: @Stiv yeah when solving this this was the only group I managed to get :P I think the actual definition is rot13(pbagnvaf gur fbhaq 'sbhe')

Comment: ughhh, knew it! I searched for "commodore fifteen" but it didn't give me any relevant results D:

Comment: All completely correct now, well done :) The checkmark is yours!

Comment: Great solution, and great puzzle @Stiv! I couldn't get untracked from COMMODORE (commode), BELOW (bowl), and POOL (loo). Spent hours trying to find the fourth. I've got problems.