# A Gentle Connect Wall

Tags: connect-wall

My last Connect Wall seemed to attract some interest from newer solvers, so I
put together this puzzle to provide a gentler introduction to this puzzle type.
**EXPERIENCED SOLVERS**: please let some of our newer contributors have a crack
at this one first!

As usual, a Connect Wall is a set of sixteen words which can be broken into
four groups of four related words, where the relationship can be described by
another word. The four words defining the relations are themselves related,
and that relation is defined by a single word as well. [Stiv's excellent post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/69217) provides more information about these puzzles.

Here are the sixteen words...good luck!

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ANTEBELLUM |    BANK    |    BLIND   |    BUG     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    DUTY    | EXPIRATION |    HOUSE   |   HUNGER   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  MADONNA   | MARMALADE  |    MUSIC   |   PEACE    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   SABER    |   START    |   TODAY'S  |   WEIGHT   |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group 1:

> LADY (Lady Antebellum, Lady Marmalade, Lady Madonna, Lady Bug)

Group 2:

> WORLD (World Peace, World Hunger, World Bank, World Music)

Group 3:

> LIGHT (Lighthouse, Lightsaber, Light Duty, Lightweight)

Group 4:

> DATE (Today’s Date, Expiration Date, Start Date, Blind Date)

So all together we have

> FIRST (First Lady, First World, First Light, and First Date) — thanks to @hexomino for the tip!

PS:

> This is only my third connect wall answer ever — I don’t get these very often — so please don’t be mad!

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say: what about people who are experienced solvers on PSE but not for this particular type of puzzle? I'm definitely not a "newer contributor" here, but I think I've never solved a Connect Wall thing. OP's decision, natch, but IMHO it's OK for you to answer this.

Comment: Seeing the answer for "antebellum", I feel obligated to add: the band changed their name, rot13(Ynql Nagroryyhz -> Ynql N), due to the... history... of the word "antebellum"

Comment: I would have gone for a different overall connecting word rot13(svefg)

Comment: Also I think the poem you reference is actually Dylan Thomas.

Comment: Shoot, my memory is bad — thanks @hexomino

Comment: You got it El-Guest! If you are new to this type of puzzle, then I think it is perfect for you to have answered. With the revised final, this is completely correct. Hope you enjoyed!

Comment: @bobble I thought about that during construction. I believe the connection remains valid and much better known to the world at large than the changed name, which is why I went this way.