# The Rock and Roll Connect Wall of Fame

Tags: knowledge, music, connect-wall

**UPDATE**: It looks like no takers yet, so let's open this up to any interested solver. Good luck!

A recent Connect Wall I wrote seemed to attract some interest from newer solvers, so I'm putting together a few of these puzzles to provide a gentler introduction to this puzzle type. **EXPERIENCED SOLVERS**: please let some of our newer contributors have a crack at this one first!

A Connect Wall is a set of sixteen words/proper nouns/phrases which can be broken into four groups of four related items, where the relationship can be described by another word/proper noun/phrase. The four items defining the relations are themselves related, and that relation is defined by a single word/proper noun/phrase as well. [Stiv's excellent post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/69217) provides more information about these puzzles.

This puzzle has the special theme that all sixteen "words" are the names of rock and roll bands (of one shape or another) from the 1960s and 1970s. The final entry linking the four groups is also a rock and roll band from the 1960s and/or 1970s. Good luck!

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    The     |    The     |    The     |            |
|            |            |            |   Camel    |
|   B-52's   |  Beatles   |   Byrds    |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Creedence  |    Deep    |  Emerson   |            |
| Clearwater |            |  Lake and  |  Genesis   |
|  Revival   |   Purple   |   Palmer   |            |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  Herman's  |            |    Led     |    The     |
|            |    Kiss    |            |   Lovin'   |
|  Hermits   |            |  Zeppelin  |  Spoonful  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|    Pink    |            |    The     |    The     |
|            |   Queen    |  Rolling   |            |
|   Floyd    |            |   Stones   | Yardbirds  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

**HINT:**

> I was searching for a hint, but ended up on YouTube watching Mojo Nixon's "Don Henley Must Die", and I love the line "Don Henley must die, don't let him get back together with Glenn Frey". I wondered if Joe Walsh, Randy Meisner and Don Felder felt left out. I guess that's not much of a hint. Or is it?

**HINT:**

> You can be twice as confident as normal that Led Zeppelin is in its group, which also contains The Lovin' Spoonful.

**HINT:**

> Remember, I (naively) thought this one would be pretty straightforward for beginners. If you get one group, getting these others should be easy.

Comment: I think what makes this difficult is that normally the words in the wall are fairly disconnected making any connection found very promising. Here, however, there are lots of possible connections between the bands meaning I'm not very confident on any group I form.

Comment: @hexomino: Guess that's the downside of writing it...I know what I meant. I'll throw another hint out there :-)

Comment: Funny - I had a connection for my working attempt which used what is suggested in Hint 2 but was even more specific so as to reduce it to exactly 4 qualifiers (couldn't get all 3 other categories to fit though). After the hint, still a lot of work to spot this complete group - by my count there are 5 options for the remaining 2 members...!

Comment: @Stiv This is not one of my Fano planes...there are definitely bands which could fit in more than one group.

Comment: @JeremyDover Got it finally! I was totally overthinking it... The category I referenced in my comment above was rot13("ONFFVFGF pnyyrq Wbua") - I got so stuck on linking the Byrds, Led Zeppelin, Queen and the Yardbirds in this way that I couldn't see anything else for a while!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The four groups are:

> **Group 1: Member called JOHN**
>  The Beatles (John Lennon)
>  Creedence Clearwater Revival (John Fogerty)
>  Led Zeppelin (John Paul Jones & John Bonham)
>  The Lovin' Spoonful (John Sebastian)
>
>  **Group 2: Member called KEITH**
>  The B-52's (Keith Strickland)
>  Emerson, Lake & Palmer (Keith Emerson)
>  The Rolling Stones (Keith Richards)
>  The Yardbirds (Keith Relf)
>
>  **Group 3: Member called PETER**
>  Camel (Peter Bardens)
>  Genesis (Peter Gabriel)
>  Herman's Hermits (Peter Noone)
>  Kiss (Peter Criss)
>
>  **Group 4: Member called ROGER**
>  The Byrds (Roger McGuinn)
>  Deep Purple (Roger Glover)
>  Pink Floyd (Roger Waters)
>  Queen (Roger Taylor)

The link between these four connections is:

> **[THE WHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Who)** - another Rock and Roll band of the same era, with members **JOHN** Entwistle, **KEITH** Moon, **PETE(R)** Townshend and **ROGER** Daltrey!

Comment: I looked at this for a while and I was certain one of the groups was going to be prog rock bands. Amazingly the connection you spotted didn't cross my mind. D'oh!

Comment: Perhaps I should apologize to you and @hexomino...I really was trying to make this one pretty straightforward. Perhaps as Fred Weasley said, "That's why it's so brilliant, because it's so pathetically dimwitted." Anyway, I hope you enjoyed it in the end!

Comment: @JeremyDover No apology necessary - just a different variety of connect-wall puzzle, and one which I still enjoyed nonetheless :) The hints certainly helped to pin it down, but it was nice to have an excuse to listen to a lot of classic rock!

Comment: If it gets one more person to try Camel, it was all worth it :-)