# A Mouldy Connect Wall

Tags: connect-wall

A recent Connect Wall I wrote seemed to attract some interest from newer solvers, so I'm putting together a few of these puzzles to provide a gentler introduction to this puzzle type. **EXPERIENCED SOLVERS**: please let some of our newer contributors have a crack at posting the answer, but by all means throw it in a comment if you crack it earlier, and I'll tag you if I open it up.

A Connect Wall is a set of sixteen words/proper nouns/phrases which can be broken into four groups of four related items, where the relationship can be described by another word/proper noun/phrase. The four items defining the relations are themselves related, and that relation is defined by a single word/proper noun/phrase as well. [Stiv's excellent post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/69217) provides more information about these puzzles. Good luck!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BITTER | BOOM | BORG | CHILL |
| COSMIC | DEATH | DOLL | FACE |
| GAME | HOO | HYPER | ICE |
| LOVE | POISON | RED | STING |

Comment: Love is there twice, is that intentional?

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 Grr...no...let me fix. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Guess

> First-timer hear. So, let me know if I need to adjust anything.
>  **CUBE** - BORG, GAME, HYPER, ICE
>  **BABY** - BOOM, DOLL, FACE, LOVE
>  **RAY** - HOO, COSMIC, DEATH, STING
>  **PILL** - BITTER, CHILL, POISON, RED
>  These all connect with 
>  **SUGAR** - CUBE, BABY, RAY, PILL

Title

> Leaving sweets out might create a moldy mess. EDIT - **OR** better yet (and Thanks to @Stiv for aiming me in this direction)
>  A [sugarloaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarloaf) which is made by shaping liquid sugar by pouring it into a mold, resembles a torpedo. 
>  And a [Mouldy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mouldy?s=t) is defined as British military slang for a torpedo. 
>  NOTE - After input from OP, I was way off, but I like it. So, I'll leave the previous statements for future knowledge seekers.
>  **INTENDED TITLE REFERENCE** - (Given by OP) - 
>  [Bob Mould](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Mould) was a leading member of the band "Sugar" in the 1990's.

Comment: Although your final connecting word fits better I would have gone for rot13(oyhr) to tie in with the idea of rot13(oyhr purrfr) for the title. +1 though

Comment: Nailed it! Final connection is what I intended. There is a more direct connection to the title...as a hint, I'm from the US so I would only use mould instead of mold as a proper term. That said, the connection is moderately obscure. As far as your answers here, since the categories are pretty straightforward, what you have is fine.

Comment: @hexomino, I see now where you would do that. okay.

Comment: I wonder whether title-wise [this](https://ourpastimes.com/history-sugar-molds-5344572.html) is what you're looking for...

Comment: @JeremyDover, I edited to change the title reference to what I hope you were looking for.

Comment: Apparently it's even more obscure than I thought...suggest looking at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Mould).