# A yummy, crunchy connect wall

Tags: word, connect-wall

A connect wall is a 4 x 4 grid, Each has 16 words inside it. They are broken into 4 groups of four words, Each has a relationship. The four words defining the relations are themselves related, And the relations are defined by a single word as well. More information on [Stiv's excellent post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/69217).

Here is the connect wall:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DIGITAL | ADVOCATE | INFLUENCE | POTENTIAL |
| CHAMP | CAPACITY | BRAIN | TIMBER |
| COPSE | MAINFRAME | WINNER | PC |
| CAPABILITY | ALLY | VINDICATOR | GROVE |

Hint 1:

> **COMPUTER** is not one of the groups.

Hint 2:

> The answer is relatively crunchy, says the title

Hints 3-5:

> ADVOCATE and WINNER are in the same group.
>  CAPACITY is not in the group where VINDICATOR is.
>  BRAIN is not in the group where ALLY is.

Last Hint:

> If you want to lead to the answer, just go zig-zag. (not the method but this is a hint okay)

Comment: Can you check my answer and say whether it is right/wrong/partially correct?

Answer (score 4):

Revised answer taking the hints into account

> TREE - copse, timber, grove, [digital](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

> RECORDS - winner, champ, vindicator, capacity

> STEM - brain, ally, advocate, influence

> CORE - potential, capability, mainframe, PC

So the joining word for all groups would be:

> APPLE

Comment: Ummmm, the instructions clearly said that there would be 4 groups.

Comment: Yes, which is why this is marked as a partial answer

Comment: Where's "ally?"

Comment: Also, all groups *need* to have four items... that's the point. If you can only put three items into a group then *it isn't a group*, or at least you haven't figured that group out yet.

Comment: Despite the other comments here (which all make fair points) I think this answer has real potential and suits the title too - if you can lose a group, shuffle its three members among the others and add the missing word into the mix, you may actually be on to something here :)

Comment: I'm with Stiv. By my reckoning, you could distribute the STEM group among the others and make it work with the additional word.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my not entirely confident answer:

> **CHAMPION** - ally, champ, vindicator, winner
>  **TREE** - advocate (??), copse, grove, timber
>  **POWER** - capability, capacity, influence, potential
>  **PROCESSOR** - brain, digital, mainframe, pc
>
>  Final answer: **APPLE** - Champion apple variety, apple tree, Power Mac from Apple computer, Apple computer processor (e.g. M1 processor).  Also an apple is yummy and crunchy which fits the title.
>
>  What I'm not sure of is "advocate".  Five words fit in the CHAMPION group including "advocate".  From the hint, vindicator and winner are in the same group, so one of "ally", "champ", or "advocate" doesn't belong.  The TREE group was missing a word, so I put "advocate" there as in "tree advocate", but it's a weak connection.

Comment: ...Partial! Cool.

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison Can you say what parts are wrong or give another hint?  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Partial Answer

> Perhaps one of the groups are PC, DIGITAL, MAINFRAME, and CAPACITY, connected to COMPUTER?

Comment: This really isn't a [significant partial answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6706); due to the nature of connect walls there will be nearly unlimited red herrings of a single group. It takes 2 *extremely* solid groups or 3 good groups to be sure enough in them that an answer is warranted, and *only then* if there's been significant time since posting. Please refrain from doing this in the future.