# A beautiful connect wall

Tags: word, connect-wall

As usual, a connect wall is a $4\times4$ grid, which has 16 words inside it. They are broken into 4 groups of 4 words,and each group has a relationship. The four words defining the relations are themselves related, and the relations are defined by a single word as well. You can find more information at [Stiv's excellent post about it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100727/connect-wall-v-s-word-web/100733#100733).

Here is the connect wall (unfortunately Markdown does not support coloring, which is crucial for this puzzle, so I've decided to stick to the image, but see text version below):

[image: connect wall]

The text version in CSV (note that the word in R1C4 is colored red):

```
UNIT,TREASURE,LAW,OCTOBER
DOWN,ROT,WHEEL,BAKER
NUTCRACKER,OUNCE,CLAY,SHOWDOWN,
LEWIS,HARRY,MCCLURE,MAIL
```

Hint 1:

> One of the 4 groups is homophonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group 1

> Words associated to **HUNT** - [Treasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scavenger_hunt), [Red October](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunt_for_Red_October), [Showdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt:_Showdown), Down

Group 2

> Words associated to **TROY** - [Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_Baker), [Ounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_weight),  [McClure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_McClure), [Lewis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_Lewis)

Group 3

> Words associated to **RED** - [Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Group), [Rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_rot), [Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Wheel/Weiser/Conari), [Clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Clay)

Group 4

> Words associated to the **CLARK/CLERK** homophones - [Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_clerk), [Nutcracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark%27s_nutcracker), [Harry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_C._Clark), [Mail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mail%20clerk#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20one%20who%20does%20clerical,mail%20in%20a%20post%20office)

and the overall connection is

> **Helen** - [Hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Hunt), [Troy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_of_Troy), [Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Clark), [Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papilio_helenus)

Title

> Helen of Troy was considered the most beautiful woman in the world in Greek mythology.

Comment: I believe that you deserved the checkmark since you've got the final answer! However, for group 3, jsm's rot13(Cbggre) was correct (and related to [rot13(Uryra Orngevk Cbggre)](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatrix_Potter))

Comment: Well, not "correct" but rather "intended". That's great that you found a different solution but the same answer.

Comment: @trolley813 Ah, sorry, I didn't really read jsm's answer as I was mostly done by then (except for the links). I take it, in that case, Harry moves to 3, unit to 2 and lewis to 4. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was intended.

Comment: Ah, yes. I did suspect the linking word (based on the title), but couldn’t make it fit with rot13(Cbggre). Still don’t quite get that link, actually.

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution for the groups:

> HUNT for Red October, Treasure, Down

> TROY McClure, Ounce (also possibly Lewis, but that’s a bit obscure)

> POTTER Harry, Wheel, Clay

That’s all I can find so far

Comment: Well done! You found 3 of 4 groups and all related words (except the obscure one). Adding a hint.