# A Connecting Wall

Tags: knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

This is, quite literally, a [connect-wall](/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle where the group's connections can be connected together to form the puzzle's answer. It has been compiled using a mixture of [connecting methods](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/100733/60644) used in the original BBC TV series, *[Only Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Only_Connect)*.

For this Connecting Wall, you will need to separate the words listed into 4 sets of 4. If the correct sets have been found, you will be able to connect the connections for the final answer for the puzzle.

Apologies if some of the elements of this puzzle have been used before - I'm relatively new to PSE and haven't reviewed all previous connecting wall puzzles.

Good luck!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BLACKLIGHT | EAMON | ESTRANGED | FRUIT MACHINE |
| HANDS | JOHNNY | KING | KLINE |
| MIKE | OWNS | PINBALL | ROSE |
| STAR | TAR | THRONE | VIRUS |

Comment: *Sees question:* Well, this title could do with being made more specific... *Sees answer:* Negative, negative - hold your fire!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the categories

Category 1

> Nicknames of characters in the movie **CON** AIR - Virus, Mike, Pinball, Johnny

Category 2

> Words which can be preceded by **NEC** to make new words - King, Kline, Rose,  Tar

Category 3

> Songs by the band THE **TING** TINGS - Blacklight, Estranged, Fruit Machine,  Hands

Category 4

> Anagrams of Watchers on the **WALL** in *Game of Thrones* - Eamon (Aemon), Owns (Snow), Star (Rast), Throne (Thorne)

The overall connection

> **CON-NEC-TING WALL**

Comment: perfect answer, well done

Comment: Wow that was a tough one